# Using powershell script to unzip a folder.

Tags: powershell

I am having some problems with my powershell script to unzip a zipped folder. Any one have any solutions? I have searched the net but everyone seem to be using powershell v1.0 and above.

Does anyone have a solution to unzip a zipped folder for powershell 1.0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of problems, exactly, you have? Powershell 1.0 is quite different than newer versions, so maybe your best bet is to use 7zip or some other tool.

Comment: The best solution : update Powershell to a supported version. Keep in mind that Powershell version 1 is very limited compared to version 2 (and version 2 is very limited compared to 3+). Powershell 2 is reaching the deprecated state in a few months, using Powershell version 1 is just something that should be avoided at all costs.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a Powershell 1 to test with (who does these days!) but I found this snippet on my machine from the days before Expand-Archive was available:

```
# Unzip stuff
$shell = new-object -com shell.application
$zip_file = get-item "C:\temp\c1.zip"
$Location = $shell.namespace("C:\temp")
$zipFolder = $shell.namespace($zip_file.fullname)
$Location.Copyhere($zipFolder.items())
```

It will unzip the file to the folder it is in. I believe it should work with PS1, but you'll have to test it yourself.

Comment: solutions like this are needed for older Powershell versions, i believe this one should work on version 1.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But how to automatically overwrite existing files? I know of the -force command but do you know where to apply it at?

Comment: In this case we are using the CopyHere method from the shell. The documentation is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx
Edit for clarification: basically $location.Copyhere($zipfolder.items(), val) where you need to look up in the documentation to figure out what you want val to be.

Comment: Thanks and sflr. When I used this code to extract, it pops out a progress bar. Is there any way I can do to suppress/hide it?

Comment: Add 4 to your val if you are using any. That amounts to "do not display a progress dialog box" according to the documentation.